# Android animation

Tags: android, animation

I wrote a suduko game for android, and want to animate tile, if the user insert wrong number.
But I don't figure how to do this? The problem is that, I have one big rectangel wich cover hole screen, and devide this rectangle in tiles, simply by drawnig lines. And now I can't figure how to animate tiles.

Hop I could explain my problem.

Sorry for bad english, and thaks for answers)

Answer (score 8):

You should not draw your board like that. I would recommend to implement one tile as a subclass of View so you can then animate each one individually.

Try this to see how animation works:

**Tile class**

```
public class Tile extends View {

private RectF mRect;
private Paint mPaint;

public Tile(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
}

public Tile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
}

public Tile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
}

private void init(){
        mRect  = new RectF(0, 0, 100, 100);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle( Paint.Style.STROKE );
        mPaint.setColor( Color.BLUE );
}

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);
    }
}
```

**Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Tile mTile;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout( this );
        layout.setBackgroundColor( Color.WHITE );
        layout.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);

        Button btn = new Button( this );
        btn.setText( "Click Me" );
        btn.setOnClickListener( this );
        layout.addView( btn );

        mTile = new Tile( this );
        layout.addView( mTile );

        setContentView( layout );
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Animation scaleAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
    mTile.startAnimation( scaleAnim );      
}
}
```

**Animation definition** (This file should be named `scale.xml` and placed under directory `/res/anim` )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="2.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="2.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

Learn more about animations [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).
To make your own animation have a look here [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html).

Hope this keeps you going.

Comment: Use Animator/AnimatorSet, Animation class is legacy code

Answer (score 3):

If you use standard views, you could look into [tween animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#tween-animation), i.e. define a set of animations, load them from the resources and attach them to your views / start the animation.

Have a look at [the spaceship jump example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#tween-animation) here.

If you do custom drawing, I'm afraid you also need to do custom animation.

Comment: I try to write custom animation, but can't solve the problem.
I have one rect which covers hole screen, and I can't animate only one part of that rect((

Answer (score 1):

Working with animation on anything before Honeycomb is a real pain. I recommend downloading the NineOldAndroids library (http://nineoldandroids.com/) and using it as imports, that way you can use the Honeycomb animation API on all versions of android (even up to 1.0).